# How to add a multiple values field to an MS Access form

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a database which records and tracks the training records for each employee within our group of companies.

One of the forms on the database is 'add training record' and currently this is done per person ID, adding the course id, date, certificate, etc. What I would love to do is be able to add multiple person IDs, as a number of people can attend the same course/ date, so I have to add the course details in many times, which is very time consuming and annoying.

Comment: I think what you need is an implementation of a Many-Many system. http://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=153458

Comment: Your description suggests the db is not properly normalized.  Since you're inexperienced, normalization may be an unfamiliar concept.  Fixing it would require table design changes, and possibly new tables ... which means you would have to revise everything you've created which depends on the old design. Does that sound like something you want to tackle?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need extensive VBA behind the scenes to do this, as well as a couple of controls to make your life easier (multi-select combo or list boxes).  You **could** do it in a text box if you want, using the semi-colon between User IDs.

Since the text box is easier, let's look at that.  What you would do is have something like this behind the Submit button:

```
Dim db as Database
Dim rec as Recordset
Dim str as String

Set db = CurrentDB
Set rec = db.OpenRecordSet("SELECT * FROM tblMyTable")

'Throw the User IDs into an array
Dim var As Variant
Dim i As Long

str = me.txtUserIDs
var = Split(str, ";")

'For every User ID, add a new record to the database
For i = 0 To UBound(var)
    rec.AddNew
    rec("UserID") = var(i)
    rec("CourseID") = Me.txtCourseID
    rec("CourseDate") = Me.txtCourseDate
    'ETC... adding fields as needed
    rec.Update
Next i
```

This is completely off-the-cuff and (of course) requires you to change the appropriate variable names, but it should give you a solid outline for how to solve the problem.